# Когда загружаю в bitmap изображение, приложение компилируется, но при запуске вылетает

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Задаю возможно глупый вопрос, но когда я загружаю изображение в bitmap
`Context cntx; Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cntx.getResources(), R.drawable.background_img);`
То приложение компилируется, но после запуска вылетает. Пишит что в приложение снова произошёл сбой. Что делать не знаю. Гуглил, но ничего не нашёл.  Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class GameView extends View{

public GameView(Context context){
  super(context);
}
Context cntx;
Paint paint;
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cntx.getResources(), R.drawable.background_img);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);
canvas.drawBitmap(background, 50, 50, paint);

}

}
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: а зачем вы создаёте новый Context? в нём нет ресурса `R.drawable.background_img`

Comment: А где надо создать контекст?

Comment: Так как getResouce не работает без контекста (это его функция)

Comment: Следует использовать контекст, предоставляемый фреймворком, а не создавать свой.

Comment: А как ? Я просто новичок и не очень понимаю

Answer (score 1):

```
Context cntx;
```

Неясно что это и зачем. Вы не можете создавать контекст, вы можете только использовать тот, что дает вам система. В случае View - во всех возможных конструкторах контекст приходит параметром, вот его и используйте

```
public GameView(Context context){
   super(context);
   background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background_img);
}
```

Только если пихать такое в конструктор, то могут начаться проблемы из-за того, что у View несколько конструкторов. Если вызовется конструктор с другим набором параметров, то этот перегруженный конструктор не вызовется и картинка не считается. Либо перегрузите все, либо вынесите этот код в другое место(но все еще внутри вашей вьюшки). Во View всегда доступен метод getContext()